# Using Reactive Forms for read data from one service and create a list

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

I created a service with some product with a name and a code which one. I want to use that list of objects and create a list. 
Please help me!
:)
Thank you

product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DateService {
  get pdcSol(): { cod: string; denumire: string }[] {
return this._pdcSol;
}

constructor() { }    

private _pdcSol = [
{cod: '065095', denumire: 'Pompa de caldura sol apa F1145-8 '},
{cod: '065096', denumire: 'Pompa de caldura sol apa F1145-10 '},
{cod: '065097', denumire: 'Pompa de caldura sol apa F1145-12 '}];
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { DateService } from '../date.service';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private pdc: DateService) {}
}
```

home.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formSol">
    <select formControlName="modelPDC">
      <option *ngFor="let pdcSol of this.pdc._pdcSol.denumire" 
       [value]="pdcSol">{{ pdcSol }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: your iteration should be : `<option *ngFor="let pdcSol of this.pdc.pdcSol>`

Comment: Sorry, i edit my post, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the service to component public property.

```
import { DateService } from '../date.service';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
formSol: FormGroup;
dropdownArr:any;
constructor(private pdc: DateService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(){
 this.dropdownArr = this.pdc.pdcSol;
 this.formSol = this.formBuilder.group({
   modelPDC: ['']
 });
 this.formSol.controls['modelPDC'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {console.log(value);});
}

}
```

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formSol">
    <select formControlName="modelPDC">
      <option *ngFor="let pdcSol of this.dropdownArr" 
       [value]="pdcSol.denumire">{{ pdcSol.denumire }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: done! But tell me please, how can I pass the selected data from that list into a <p>{{ ? }}</p>

Comment: You can access it using 'modelPDC'. update the answer above.

Comment: I see only a [object Object]

Comment: Thank you again. It works: {{  this.formSol.controls['modelPDC'].value }}

Answer (score 0):

Create a get variable in the component and call the service `pdcSols`

```
export class HomeComponent {
  get pdcSols(): { cod: string; denumire: string }[] {
      return this.pdc.pdcSol;
  }
}
```

And call it in the template

```
  <option *ngFor="let pdcSol of pdcSols" [value]="pdcSol.cod">{{ pdcSol.denumire }}</option>
```